# ElasticSearch Query for each extension get the sum of its length

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I'm looking to find the sum of each extension.
The json file contains

Sample code

```
       {"index":{"_id":"202"}} 
        "length":500000
         "extension":".jpeg"
```

Output wanted

Key: Jpeg 10000000
Key: docx 20000000

Tried code

```
        GET /crud_sample2/Customer_Info/_search?extension
          { 
          "aggs": {
          "sum": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "length"
              }
          }
           }
        }
```

Output

"key": 500000,
 "doc_count": 15

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354830/trying-to-upload-json-files-using-command-line-error-message-for-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
GET /crud_sample2/Customer_Info/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "sum": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "extension",
        "order": {"total_length": "desc"}
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_length": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "length"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway you can sort it like     "sort": {
    "total_length": " desc"
  },
  "size": 10
}

Comment: another question sorry not really related to this but. i tried to import json files to sense using the curl -XPOST ect. I had to download curl but when i run this command it says missing libcurl-4 any ideas what i need to do

Comment: Please ask another question, so this one stays clean :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354830/trying-to-upload-json-files-using-command-line-error-message-for-elasticsearch